# Expand input, output or error

Tags: bash, output, input

What I want to do is to ask the user to enter one line and send to standard ouput.

I tried get the input to carry out a conditional question, but there's no way to expand a input (in this case is input 0, but can be output 1 or error 2). In this scenario I want to ask and read the user input from standard input and send to standard input/output, after get this and verify if have something (if is non-zero). The code looks like (maybe looks confused in this case you can skip and use the description above)

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/bash

read>&0

if [[ -n $my_input_expanded ]] ; then
  echo "hello word"
fi
```

Here `read` make the role of ask the user the input (can be another command, but I don't know which can be here), and the variable $my_input_expaded was some operation like redirection of input `0>` (I know this is just to file, but it's something like this), but instead redirection is expansion of input.

Comment: I would suggest you paste your code into https://shellcheck.net/, fix the errors as best you can, and then come back here if you have further questions on your code

Comment: Start your code with a line such as `#/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh`. Make sure you're using that shell to run your code (hint: if you're using `[[ ... ]]` then it needs to be `bash`)

Comment: Thank, I make the corrections in the code @roaima, sorry I started today, the question be good to understand?

Comment: `read` does not usually output anything on standard output, so redirecting its output won't do anything useful.

Comment: But I can't use something like redirection operator as `>&0` to send what go to variable to standard input/output @they, or some another command to read the standard input to manipulate after without variable?

Comment: `cat` reads standard input and passes it onto standard output, as does most other Unix tools that works on streams, like `sed`, `awk`, `tr`, and many others. They all read standard input, optionally modifies the stream, and outputs it to standard output. It's unclear what you want to do.

Comment: Sorry, in this case I want ask the user input just one time and send to standard input/ouput, but I don't know the command to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should study a beginner's guide rather then trying to guess at the syntax. Shell script is strange. Really. Here's a version that does what you've described:

```
#!/bin/sh

# read a line of text into the variable "$line"
IFS= read -r line

# check if the result contains any text
if [ -n "$line" ]
then
    # it does, so output a simple response including the given text
    echo "hello: $line"
fi
```

Comment: Hi, thank, but is almost this, but instead I want read without a variable and only a operation, I know that's just variable, but if possible use just a operation in some way like `cout << "insert your name" << endl` in c++ but in bash, world be `[[ -n "read" ]]` I will thank so much

Comment: No. This is shell script, not C++. Unless you mean little just `cat` by itself...?

Comment: Thank so much, I'll use this in my scripts, and I write wrong the c++ code, instead is c# with "if (Console.Readline()) something" (more easy to explain).

Comment: @MatheusdosSantosBonifácio, `cout << "..."` doesn't read anything, it prints. Maybe you meant `cin >> str`, but you still need a variable if you need to do something conditionally depending on what the input was. Anyway, best forget about the silly use of the `<<` and `>>` operators with C++ streams, it's not like pretty much any other programming language has a similar syntax for reading and writing, and they might get confused with shell redirections.